# How to set SOAP protocol for a ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, web

I m newbie to ASP.NET web services.
I have written my web service, web method. I want the output of my web service to be in SOAP rather than the default HTTP POST protocol.
How do i do that?
I need the output to be SOAP as i need to deserialize the xml file, in my web application where i will be consuming the web service.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
  1.In the Web Service Details window, select an operation for that Web service.
  2.On the Diagram menu, choose Properties.
  3.In the Properties window, set the appropriate SOAP properties under the Implementation heading.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where will I find the Web Service Details window?